# When implementing Stripe into react native getting the error of the return_url

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use stripe in my react native app. In fact, everything seems to work until the last step. I keep getting the error that I have to provide a "return_url" for the type "Ideal" I'm using. This is indeed the case with web, only if I add that in react native this error continues to occur.

My code looks like this:

```
const fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`fetchurl`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({amount:'1000'}),
      })
      .then(res => {
              
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.client_secret)
        setClientSecret(data.client_secret)

      });

    };

    const handlePayPress = async () => {
        setBankName("abn_amro");
      
        const clientScretLet= await fetchPaymentIntentClientSecret();

  
      const { error, paymentIntent } = await confirmPayment(clientSecret, {
        type:'Ideal',
     
        billingDetails:{
          name: 'Joppe - app',
        },
        return_url:'https://google.com'
        
      });
    
      if (error) {
        Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message);
      } else if (paymentIntent) {
        
        Alert.alert(
          'Success',
          `The payment was confirmed successfully! currency: ${paymentIntent.currency}`
        );
      }
    };
```

So I get a clientSecret etc. so those steps work, only I receive this error:

[image]

In the steps in the documentation they don't use a return_url, the documentation I followed can be found here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ideal/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native#react-native-handle-deep-linking

Anyone have an idea what I need to change to get to the payment and back in the app?

Comment: If you've set up deep linking as instructed in those docs, `return_url` should be something like `yourapp://your/deep/link`.

Comment: correct, you need to pass a return_url param on calling `confirmPayment()` and also set up your iOS app for deep linking: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#return-url

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the documentation there's no extra parameter where you can enter `return_url` in `confirmPayment` method. But looking further in the docs I found that you can enter the `return_url` as `urlScheme` in the [StripeProvider](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=custom#stripe-initialisation):

```
import { StripeProvider } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';

function App() {
  return (
      <StripeProvider
          publishableKey="pk_test_qblFNYngBkEdjEZ16jxxoWSM"
          urlScheme="your-url-scheme" // required for 3D Secure and bank redirects
          merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.{{YOUR_APP_NAME}}" // required for Apple Pay
      >
        // Your app code here
      </StripeProvider>
  );
}
```

You need have to add deep linking in your application and enter that in your `urlScheme`.

If you are using `initStripe` inside a specific component you can enter your urlScheme in [that](https://stripe.dev/stripe-react-native/api-reference/index.html#initStripe).

Hope this answers your question.